# DotLiquid using variables inside tags

Tags: c#, liquid, dotliquid

Is there any option to use variables inside tags like,

```
{% for product in category.products | limit: {{section.limit}} %}
```

I've tried using capture or assign didn't work for me.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `{% for product in category.products | limit: section.limit %}`

**Edit after your comment :**

The only way I cast String to Integer is :

`{% assign limit = section.limit | plus: 0 %}`

then `{% for product in category.products | limit: limit %}`.

And Integer to String : `{% assign str = 1 | append: "" %} => str == "1"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem was, section.limit variable's type. It's not working if it's string. So I defined a custom filter for converting string to int. It worked. Can you suggest a smarter way for this?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Hi @DavidJacquel, I am experimenting with something similar and it seems like when i do something like {{"now" | date: "%s" | plus: 0 | minus: 0 }}... the minus seems to trigger an error. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: @MatthewHartz, I can't reproduce this. Thank you to ask a real question with all necessary details like error message or even repository url.